# Does $a\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\gcd(n,a(m-a))=1$ exist for every $(m,n)\not=(\text{odd},\text{even})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

When I was thinking about the greatest common divisors, I noticed that we seem to be able to find at least one **integer** $a$ such that 
$$\gcd(n,a(m-a))=1$$
for every pair of **positive integers** $(m,n)$ such that $(m,n)\not=(\text{odd},\text{even})$.

**Examples** :

- For $(m,n)=(5,7)$, we can take $a=1$.
- For $(m,n)=(4,7)$, we can take $a=-1$.
- For $(m,n)=(4,6)$, we can take $a=5$.

However, I have not been able to prove that.

If we can always take a **prime** $a\ (\gt m+n)$ such that 
$$\text{$a-m$ is a prime},$$
then we win. But I think it is another big problem.

(As a user Ofir Schnabel points out, we cannot take such primes for odd $m$. Also, if $m$ is even, then it is [an open conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) in number theory. So this way, which is just one idea, does not seem to solve the problem.)

Maybe I'm missing something important. Can anyone help?

> **Question** : Can we say that there exists at least one **integer** $a$ such that 
>   $$\gcd(n,a(m-a))=1$$
>   for every pair of **positive integers** $(m,n)$ such that $(m,n)\not=(\text{odd},\text{even})$ ?

Comment: Clearly for odd $m$ you can't take prime $a$ such that $a-m$ is prime.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: You are right. I forgot to mention that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: And for even $m$ you need that there will be two primes with difference $m$. This is an open conjecture in number theory.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: That's right. And taking such primes is just one idea. My question may be solved by another idea. That's why I'm asking this here.

Comment: Just thought to pointing it out so pepole will avoid this approch. nice question :).

Comment: @OfirSchnabel: Thanks so much! Your comments are very helpful. (I should have mentioned what you said in the question, though:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is prime, then there is $a$ such that $n\nmid a(m-a)$, since among values $a=0,\dots, n-1$, at most two are such that $n\mid a(m-a)$: it is $0$ and $m\mod n$. So if $n>2$, then there are at least $n-2$ values that fit, and if $n=2$, then, from your additional condition, $m$ is even, so the value $a=1$ fits.

Now, if $n = p_1^{d_1}\dots p_k^{d_k}$, where $p_i$ are prime, then there are $a_1, \dots, a_k$ such that $p_i\nmid a_i(m-a_i)$ for all $i = 1, \dots, k$. By Chinese remainder theorem, there is $a$ such that $a\equiv a_i\pmod {p_i}$ for all $i$. Then $a(m-a)\equiv a_i(m-a_i) \pmod {p_i}$, i.e., $a(m-a)$ is not divisible by any $p_i$, i.e., $(n,a(m-a))=1$.

Comment: Ah, got it! What I'm missing is the theorem. Thank you.